# Powershell elseif is not recognized

Tags: powershell

Why am I getting the error with this code? The term 'elseif' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

```
    $EAFRID=($item.name.Split("_")[2])
        if ($EAFRID -match "EAFRID")
        { 
             Write-Host "EAFR is $EAFR"
        }

    $AppID= ($item.name.Split("_")[1])                  
            elseif($AppID -match "CPL")
            {               
            Write-Host "CPL is $AppID"
            }

           else{    
            $OtherID = ($item.name.Split("_")[0])
                            Write-Host "other is $OtherID"
                }
```

Comment: Maybe you should use `else if` instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the elseif doesn't follow immediately after the if block - the line $AppID=... is in the way. Something like this might work instead:

```
$EAFRID =($item.name.Split("_")[2])
$AppID = ($item.name.Split("_")[1])
if ($EAFRID -match "EAFRID")
{ 
     Write-Host "EAFR is $EAFR"
}
elseif ($AppID -match "CPL")
{               
    Write-Host "CPL is $AppID"
}
```

Comment: That got me past the elseif now I'm getting the same message with the else

Comment: @MrKWatkings I just did another elseif and that worked.

Comment: Moreover, if you've had a construct as follows:
`if (some_predicate_here) {

         #actions here

    }

    elseif (another_predicate) {

        #fallback scenario

       
    }

    else #notice the absence of curly braces {} surrounding

        #other sentence here`
**you'd get the same mistake**. So beware to surround your sentences with the proper curly braces.